# obtener los ultimos archivos creados desde una carpeta

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arraylist

Tengo una function que me da la lista de todos los archivos desde un repertorio:

```
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp");
List<string> filesList = array1.ToList();
```

Lo que estoy buscando en hacer es que una vez que obtenga la lista de todos los archivos, pueda crear otra lista con solamente los ultimos archivos creados de este dia.

Tengo este otro codigo el cual me da el ultimo archivo creado, pero no se como podria aplicarselo a la otra lista que busco crear:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
              orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
              elect f).First();
```

Saludos,

Comment: si dices `los ultimos archivos creados de este dia` estas haciendo referencia a que solo quieres algunos archivos de ese dia, pero si es asi con que criterio? o lo que buscas son los archivos del dia actual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas los archivos creados en el dia podrias hacer

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp");

List<string> filesList = (from f in files
                           let fileInfo = new FileInfo(f)
                           where fileInfo.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today
                         select f).ToList();
```

de esta forma obtienes una lista de archivos en una lista de string comparando solo la fecha con la actual

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciona de maravilla!